# Можно ли повесить TextChangedListener на android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

Tags: android, android-search-view

Добавили виджет поиска в toolbar:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search"/>
```

Как на него повесить что-нибудь вроде TextChangedListener?

UPD

```
public boolean onPrepareMenuOptions(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                sferaAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Все ли здесь верно? Не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В onPrepareOptionsMenu найдите ваш SearchView в виде MenuItem в меню по его ID.
2. Получите ссылку на сам SearchView методом getActionView
3. Теперь вы можете повесить на него TextChangedListener

А вот в XML это сделать нельзя

Comment: Второй пункт разверните, пожалуйста

Comment: @Новичок, Как-то так: `SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView()`

Comment: Это сделали. Что-то в методах у searchview не могу найти TextChangedListener

Comment: setOnQueryTextListener - оно?

Comment: Юрий, добавил изменения. Студия ругается на @Override, поэтому я его не использую. В таком виде не работает, все ли верно?

Comment: @Новичок, выглядит нормально. Что значит "не работает" - вылетает или ничего не происходит? Методы вызываются? Может просто адаптер не обновляется и надо его обновить так: sferaAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()? Может этот адаптер не присоединён к списку? Или данные в нём не те? Мало инфы

Comment: Ничего не происходит. Этот слушатель на edittext , который рядом, работает.

Comment: @Новичок, как вы определили что ничего не происходит? Выведите что-то в логи из методов - может они работают, просто действия в них не так описаны.

Comment: Расставил Toast'ы, ничего не происходит. onPrepareMenuOptions is never used , а @Override, ругается "Method doesn't override method from its superclass"

Comment: @Новичок, а у вас изначально метод не тот. Вам нужен onPrepareOptionsMenu а не  onPrepareMenuOptions как вы написали. Вы перепутали слова метсами